# Change container size inside an expanded

Tags: flutter

I need a `Container` to be the size of its contents. It is currently the correct width but the height is too much because the `Container` is inside an `Expanded`, therefore the `Container` takes the height of the `Expanded`. Is it possible to fix this?

It doesn't help if you set the height of the container.

The page with the Expanded:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: SmallContainers(),
                    ),
                    flex: 2),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: OtherContainers(),
                    ),
                    flex: 3),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          flex: 1),
    ],
  ),
```

The page with the smaller Containers that I need its height smaller:

```
Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text("Different content"),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use SizedBox

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
  child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text("Different content"),
      ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I've already tried this, it only changes the width, not the height

Comment: make sense, because the expanded flex get percent of your height

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping small containers with `Expanded`, wrap it with `IntrinsicHeight` widget. This widget sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height.

Sample code below:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
                 child: Container(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 child: SmallContainers(),
                   ),
                ),
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my containers disappear, so not working yet